# how to start and stop broadcast receiver on click of buttons in android

Tags: exception, permissions, broadcastreceiver

I want to start and stop a broadcast on click of button

```
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isStopped) {
                stopAnim(start);
                isStopped = false;
                checkStatus();
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
                MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(acbroadcast , intentFilter);

                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isStopped) {
                stopAnim(stop);
                isStopped = true;
                checkStatus();
                MainActivity.this.unregisterReceiver(acbroadcast);
            }
        }
    });
```

but when I run the app it throws an exception

```
06-30 20:30:32.541 27577-27577/com.android.boltage.unplugbroadcast E/AndroidRuntime:
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.android.boltage.unplugbroadcast, PID: 27577
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED from pid=27577, uid=10149
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3005)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1515)
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:384)
     at com.android.boltage.unplugbroadcast.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this 
we can simply invoke the service class which will further register the broadcast receiver and clicking on stop button will destroy the service and unregister the broadcast receiver
this approach made a solution for my problem